# Bookmarks for new account

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have decided to use Google chrome at work, through a new work-based address and login. Despite this, it has imported all of my personal bookmarks and I certainly do not want them on my work screen.

How do I get rid of them from this account, or, is it good-bye Google?

Comment: Just reset Google Chrome, and don't login to Chrome. If you never login to Chrome, it won't sync. Or if you still want / need to login to Chrome, there is an option to not sync stuff. Under Settings - Advanced Sync Settings (or if you really don't want it, just click on Disconnect your Google Account)

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate Chrome profiles for home and work: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en-GB